# Inequality from a point in plane to a triangle OR Inequality on a quadrilateral

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, euclidean-geometry, triangles

If points $A$, $B$, $C$ form a triangle in euclidean space and $D$ is another point in the plane of the triangle, the problem is to show that :

$\frac{AB}{DA + DB} + \frac{BC}{DB + DC} \ge \frac{AC}{DA + DC}$

[Figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWKZj.png)

I verified that it holds for more than several million positions of point $D$, including when point $D$ is inside triangle $ABC$. However, I can't seem to give a proof for it.
The only inequality that resembled the one above was the Ptolemy's theorem which gives a relation between the four sides of a quadilateral made from points $A,B,C, D$ and two diagonals $AC,BD$:

$AB.DC + BC.DA \ge AC.DB$ which in other terms is $\frac{AB}{DA \cdot DB} + \frac{BC}{DB \cdot DC} \ge \frac{AC}{DA \cdot DC}$

This has multiplication in the denominator but what I am looking for is addition. Any ideas on how to go about it or perhaps some inequality results that can be applied to prove it ? Or do you see a special instance wherein the inequality doesn't hold?.

Comment: But why close?! I enjoy this question.

Comment: The question is elementary. Yet, there are many publications in research journals on inequalities even for triangles. One example is the Erdős–Mordell inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Mordell_inequality).

Comment: Good portion of questions here are 'elementary', whatever this means.

Comment: I didn't mean that "elementary" is bad. The emphasis of my comment was on the "Yet". Just to make sure.

Comment: Commenting that Suvrit's answer to [the follow-up question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229989/what-is-this-distance-about) gives a reference and a generalization of the positive answer to this question.

Comment: @NikWeaver Just to spell that generalization out: $AB / M(DA, DB) + BC / M(DB, DC) \ge AC / M(DA, DC)$ where $M : \mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ is a symmetric function in a wider class that includes $M(x, y) = x + y$ (the original question here), $M(x, y) = x y$ (Ptolemy's inequality), $M(x, y) = (\frac{1}{2}(x^p + y^p))^{q \over p}$ (p-q relative metrics) and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to streamline the proof a bit.

If $AC=0$ then the inequality in question is obvious. So, assume that $AC\ne0$. Multiplying both sides of the inequality by $(AD + BD) (AD + CD) (BD + CD)$, rewrite it as 
$$
 L:=(AD + CD) (AD\ BC + AB\ BD + BC\ BD + AB\ CD)
 -AC (AD + BD) (BD + CD)\ge0. 
$$
Clearly, $L$ is concave in $BD$. 
So, in view of Ptolemy's inequality $AB\ CD + BC\ AD\ge AC\ BD$, without loss of generality either $BD=0$ or $BD=(AB\ CD + BC\ AD)/AC$. 
But, by the triangle inequality $AB + BC \ge AC$,
$$L\big|_{BD=0}=AD^2 BC + AD (AB + BC - AC) CD + AB\ CD^2\ge0
$$
and 
$$
 AC\ L\big|_{BD=(AB\ CD + BC\ AD)/AC} 
=\big((AB + BC)^2 - AC^2\big) AD\ CD + AB\ BC (AD - CD)^2\ge0.    
$$
This completes the proof.

In conclusion, one may note that inequality in question may fail to hold in some metric spaces $M$, even if $M$ is a normed space. Let e.g. $M={\mathbb R}^2$ with the $\ell^1_2$ norm $\|(x,y)\|:=|x|+|y|$ for $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$, and then let $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, $C=(1,1)$, $D=(0,1)$, so that 
$AB=BC=AD=CD=1$ and $AC=BD=2$. Here $XY:=\|X-Y\|$ for any $X$ and $Y$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: The solution is now quite elementary.

Comment: Does this hold in any metric space? I.e., if $X$ is a metric space and $d \in X$ is fixed, does $\rho'(a,b) = \frac{\rho(a,b)}{\rho(a,d) + \rho(b,d)}$ define a new metric on $X$?

Comment: Nik: The answer to your question is no. Take e.g. $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $ab=1$, $ac=2$, $bc=1$, $ad=1$, $bd=2$, $cd=1$, where $xy:=\rho(x,y)$ for $x$ and $y$ in $X$.

Comment: I have streamlined the proof a bit and added a comment about general metric/normed spaces.

Comment: Very interesting insight to general normed spaces. According to the proof, you (@IosifPinelis) show that, the inequality holds for $\ell^2_2$ norm but not for the $\ell^1_2$ norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How does this generalize to $\mathbb{R}^3$ space ?  More precisely, am I correct to assert that it holds for $\ell^1_2$ and $\ell^2_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space ?
Thank you for your time @IosifPinelis

Comment: A small perturbation of (say) one of the points $A,B,C,D$ will extend the example to the case when the affine hull of the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is of dimension $3$ (obviously, it cannot be greater than $3$). E.g., one may let $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$, $C=(1,1,0)$, $D=(0,1,h)$, where $h$ is a nonzero real number which is close enough to $0$, with the $\ell_3^1$ norm $\|(x,y,z)\|:=|x|+|y|+|z|$ for $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$. Then the inequality in question will continue to fail to hold.

Answer (score 2):

As we see from the solution by Iosif Pinelis, triangle inequality for $ABC$ and Ptolemy inequality for $A,B,C,D$ are enough. In particular, this holds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and in any Ptolemaic space.

Here is bit simplified argument of Iosif Pinelis. Denote $AB=\gamma$, $BC=\alpha$, $AC=\beta$, $DA=a$, $DB=b$, $DC=c$. We have (1) and (2) and want (3): 
\begin{align}
\alpha+\gamma\geqslant \beta\,\,\,\,(1)\\
\frac ab\alpha+\frac cb\gamma\geqslant \beta \,\,\,\,(2)\\
\frac {a+c}{b+c}\alpha+\frac {a+c}{a+b}\gamma\geqslant \beta.\,\,\,\,(3)
\end{align}
If $b\leqslant \min (a,c)$, (3) follows from (1). If $b\geqslant \max (a,c)$, (3) follows from (2) (since $(a+c)/(c+b)\geqslant a/b$.) Finally, if $b$ lies between $a$ and $c$, multiplying (1) and (2) by the factor $\frac{b(a+c)}{(b+a)(b+c)}$ and summing up we get 
$$
\frac {a+c}{b+c}\alpha+\frac {a+c}{a+b}\gamma\geqslant \frac{2b(a+c)}{(b+a)(b+c)}\beta\geqslant \beta
$$
as desired.

Comment: Fedor, I don't understand your inequality (2). In Ptolemy's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy's_theorem) $AB\ CD+BC\ AD\ge AC\ BD$, each product contains each of the letters $A,B,C,D$ once, whereas in your inequality (2) the product $a\alpha=AB\,AD$ (say) contains $A$ twice (and does not contain $C$).

Comment: it was a misprint

Comment: Now it looks all right.