# What is this distance about?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, terminology

For points $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ denote $$d(a,b)=\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a\|+\|b\|}.$$
[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229907/inequality-from-a-point-in-plane-to-a-triangle-or-inequality-on-a-quadrilateral) question by Ritesh Ahuja (positive answered by Iosif Pinelis) says that $d$ is a metric. My questions are:

1) was it studied, does it have a name?

2) may it be viewed as a mix of Eucledian metrics in the sense 
$$
d(a,b)=\int \|F(a,t)-F(b,t)\|d\mu(t)
$$
for some function $F(a,t)$ on $a\in \mathbb{R^n}\setminus \{0\}$, $t\in (\Omega,\mu)$ is some measure space? For example, metric
$$
\frac{\|a-b\|}{\|a\|\cdot \|b\|},
$$
corresponding to Ptolemy inequality, is nothing but $\|F(a)-F(b)\|$, where $F(a)=a/\|a\|^2$ is inversion. Here $\Omega$ is a trivial 1-point measure space.

Comment: This is just a hasty guess, but if you map to the $n$-sphere by stereographic projection do you get something "close" to the usual metric on the sphere? For n=1 this is not quite right but it feels like the right kind of "flavour"

Comment: Not sure. If $a$ is fixed and $b$ is very large, the distance approaches 1, while stereographic projections may be arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first distance is a special case of the so-called [p-q relative metric](https://books.google.com/books?id=q_7FBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA362&ots=QY9TbHWREw&dq=p%20q%20relative%20metric&pg=PA362#v=onepage&q=p%20q%20relative%20metric&f=false), which is in general defined on any Ptolemaic space as
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{\|x-y\|}{\left(\tfrac12(\|x\|^p + \|y\|^p)\right)^{q/p}}.
\end{equation*}
The book linked above provides more pointers (special cases include names like *p-relative metric* (Klamkin-Meir metric), *Schattschneider metric*, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Later generalizations notwithstanding (as noted already), this particular one...

$$
d(a, b) = \frac{\lVert a - b \rVert}{\lVert a \rVert + \lVert b \rVert}
$$

...was originally called "*a multiplicative metric*" in the namesake article published in 1976 by [Schattschneider, Doris J.. "A Multiplicative Metric". Mathematics Magazine 49.4 (1976): 203–205](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690124) where she proved that $d(a, b)$ is in fact a metric on $\mathbb R$.